# Oracle SQL text field calculations

Tags: sql, oracle

Using `Oracle SQL` I have a table containing a text field representing an equation (for example `5*5`). I would like to create a view which displays the value of this equation (in this example `25`).

I have seen other posts recommend creating custom Functions, however I would like to avoid this.

Please note that the equations can be much more complicated than simple multiplication. Such as:

```
Exp(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001
```

Thank you.

Comment: give an example of a more complex calculation you'd like to handle.

Comment: Exp(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a table like this:

```
create table expressions(e) as (
    select 'Exp(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001' from dual
   )
```

This could be a way:

```
create view expressions_evaluated as
select e,
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml
        ('select ' || e || ' as result from dual')
       ),'/ROWSET/ROW/RESULT')) as result
from expressions
```

the result:

```
select * from expressions_evaluated

E                                                   RESULT
----------------------------------------------- ----------
Exp(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001 .000226724
```

Comment: That works great, is it possible for this to work with an equation such as the following as well? It errors out when I attempt your solution on the following equation Exp(0.448 + 1.254 * LN(PI(.59/40000))) * 5

Comment: This only makes Oracle to evaluate an expression, so it gives the same result that you would have by doing, for example, `select 5*5 from dual`. This way, if you try `5*PI`, Oracle gives an error because `PI` is not defined. To do so, you would need a way to parse your string and substitute values (that should have been stored somewhere), but I don't see a way to do this in in view (SQL). Consider, for example, what could happen if you would define 3 variables `P`, `PI`, `I`; how should `PI+1` be evaluated?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL doesn't provide an `eval` function to evaluate an expression out of the box.

So you may either implement it in PL/SQL (search for `Oracle PL/SQL Eval function`) or
simpler you may create a dynamic view based on the content of the table.

**Example - your data**

```
select * from tab;
EXPR                                        
--------------------------------------------
(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001
5*5
```

**Query producing the dynamic view**

```
select 'create view my_expr as ' as tab from dual union all
select q'{select q'[}'|| expr ||q'{]' as expr, }'|| expr ||' as result from dual union all' from tab union all
select 'select null, null from dual where 1=0' from dual;
```

Note, that the last line is only dummy to get rid of the last union all

The query returns

```
create view my_expr as 
select q'[(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001]' as expr, (-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001 as result from dual union all
select q'[5*5]' as expr, 5*5 as result from dual union all
select null, null from dual where 1=0
```

Which is the script for the view definetion.

After creating the view you get the result:

```
select * from my_expr;

EXPR                                             RESULT
-------------------------------------------- ----------
(-2.02 + 2.46 * LN(0.66)) * 0.95 * 5 * 0.001 -0,014450298
5*5                                                  25
```

You may enter any valid Oracle expression in the input table. While you create the view the syntax check will be done, teh evaluation is done while selecting from the view.

Note that you should take **some care of security aspects** in case that the expression is an arbitrary input.